# How can I take several figures as once from my terminal

Tags: c

I'm trying to take several figures from my terminal to make my calculator work correctly. I would have to take every figures before a space : eg. 160 + 23 I have to get 160 for my first variable, "+" for my second one and 23 for my last one.

Here is the code :

`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define BUFFER 25

void calculatrice(double,char,double);

int main(){
    char *str;
    printf("************************************************\n");
    printf("ecrire sous la forme x + y avec les espaces pour avoir un resultat\n");
    printf("quit pour quitter\n");
    printf("************************************************\n");
    char *text = calloc(1,1), buffer[BUFFER];
    while( fgets(buffer, BUFFER , stdin)){
        if (!strncmp(buffer, "quit",strlen("quit"))){
            break;
        }
        if (!strncmp(buffer, "flush",strlen("flush"))){
            system("clear");
        }
        text = realloc( text, strlen(text)+1+strlen(buffer) );
        if( !text ){
            strcat( text, buffer);
            printf("%s\n", buffer);
        }   
        double nb1 = strtol(&buffer[0], &str, 10);
        double nb2 = strtol(&buffer[3], &str, 10);
        calculatrice(nb1, buffer[2], nb2);
    }
    return 0;
}

void calculatrice(double value_1, char operator, double value_2){
    double result = 0;
    switch (operator)
    {
    case '+':
        result = value_1 + value_2;
        printf("resultat : %f\n",result);
        break;

    case '-':
        result = value_1 - value_2;
        printf("resultat : %f\n",result);
        break;

    case '*':
        result = value_1 * value_2;
        printf("resultat : %f\n",result);
        break;
    
    case '/':
        result = value_1 / value_2;
        printf("resultat : %f\n",result);
        break;

    case '%':
        result = (int)value_1 % (int)value_2;
        printf("resultat : %f\n",result);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

`

I tried to make loops and conditions which triggers when there is a space to get each part necessary for my calculator, but the result was completely wrong.

Comment: No need for `%` and `(int)`.  `result = fmod(value_1, value_2);`

Answer (score 1):

Given the user input of

```
160 + 23
```

then

`&buffer[0]` will be the string `"160 + 23\n"`,
`&buffer[3]` will be the string `" + 23\n"`, and
`buffer[2]` will be the character `'0'`.

[`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) converts the initial part of a string to a `long`. With base-10, the string may begin with an arbitrary amount of whitespace, and then an optional sign character of `'+'` or `'-'`.

For `"160 + 23\n"`, the converted value will be `160` as it stops on the first non-digit character encountered (a `' '` after `'0'`).

For `" + 23\n"`, the converted value will be `0`, after skipping the initial whitespace, reading the sign character `'+'`, and stopping on the first non-digit character encountered (a `' '` after `'+'`).

These resulting values are then implicitly converted to `double` during the assignment.

Note, to convert a string directly to a `double`, use [`strtod`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof).

The effect is that, with the given user input, `calculatrice` is called as:

```
calculatrice(160.0, '0', 0.0);
```

There is no match for `'0'` in the `switch`, and thus the function quietly returns.

---

You must find the correct string tokens more carefully, but how this is done depends greatly on the requirements of your program. Two interesting functions in the standard library are:

[`strtok`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) can be used to break a string into tokens, based on a set of delimiting characters.

[`sscanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) can be use to convert well formatted strings into data.

Here is a cursory example of using `sscanf`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double calculatrice(double, char, double);

int main(void)
{
    puts("************************************************");
    puts("ecrire sous la forme x + y avec les espaces pour avoir un resultat");
    puts("quit pour quitter");
    puts("************************************************");

    char buffer[128];

    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin)) {
        if ('q' == *buffer)
            break;

        if ('f' == *buffer) {
            system("clear");
            continue;
        }

        char op;
        double lhs, rhs;

        if (3 == sscanf(buffer, "%lf %c%lf", &lhs, &op, &rhs))
            printf("Result: %f\n", calculatrice(lhs, op, rhs));
    }
}

double calculatrice(double a, char operator, double b)
{
    switch (operator) {
        case '+':
            return a + b;
        case '-':
            return a - b;
        case '*':
            return a * b;
        case '/':
            if (0 == b) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Division by zero detected.\n");
                break;
            }

            return a / b;
        case '%':
            if (0 == (int) b) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Division by zero detected.\n");
                break;
            }

            return (int) a % (int) b;
        default:
            fprintf(stderr, "Invalid operator [%c].\n", operator);
            break;
    }

    return 0.0;
}
```

```
************************************************
ecrire sous la forme x + y avec les espaces pour avoir un resultat
quit pour quitter
************************************************
160 + 23
Result: 183.000000
```

---

The purpose of `text` here is unclear, but the use of

```
if (!text) {
    strcat(text, buffer);
    /* ... */
```

is surely wrong, as it *guarantees* [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior) by passing the NULL pointer value to `strcat`. Otherwise, `text` is unused until this failure state.

Comment: Answer mentions "Two interesting functions", yet OP did use `strtol()`, which if done right (and maybe with `strtod()` instead), could have provided the proper tokenizing needed.